# Legal status of past TUGBoat papers

Tags: tugboat

I hope the question is acceptable here. Is it possible to upload past TUGboat papers on Institutional Open Archives to guarantee a permanent and open storage with a persistent identifier?
An example: upload the [pdf](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb35-3/tb111haralambous.pdf) from TUGBoat 35 to the [HAL](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01185086) repository.

Comment: You should probably ask TUG instead.

Comment: @daleif agree, but the question could be of interest to other users/authors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TUGboat contains the following copyright notice:

> Copyright to individual articles within this publication remains with
> their authors, so the articles may not be reproduced, distributed or
> translated without the authors’ permission.
>
> For the editorial and other material not ascribed to a particular
> author, permission is granted to make and distribute verbatim copies
> without royalty, in any medium, provided the copyright notice and this
> permission notice are preserved.

So the answer is yes, you can upload the article you mention to HAL, but only if you are able to obtain permission from (in this case) Yannis Haralambous.